# order by ndb.IntegerProperty returns an empty list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

please see my code below:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
class TestModel(ndb.Model):
    num = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False, default=0, indexed=False)
    txt = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
class TestHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        for i in range(0, 20):
            m = TestModel(num=i, txt=' hello world ')
            m.put()
        data = TestModel.query().order(TestModel.num).fetch(20) # empty list!
        data = TestModel.query().order(-TestModel.num).fetch() # empty list!
        count = TestModel.query().count() # 20
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', TestHandler)
], debug=True)
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I've read this article https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries?hl=ru#order

But I'm confused with it, please help me with this

udp: 
it works when testmodel entities is more than 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to order your query by `TestModel.num`, you should enable the datastore index of `TestModel.num`.

`num = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False, default=0, indexed=True)`

or

`num = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False, default=0)` # By default indexed=True

To get already added entities in Query result, You need to re-put() all those entities.

More info about Datastore index: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes